# ¿Cómo hacer un ViewPager con Fragments que muestren un ListView con todos los registros de una tabla en SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-viewpager

Estoy intentando hacer un `ViewPager` con diferentes fragments que muestran un listview con los registros de una tabla. Esos fragments muestran importes de un dia (o caja) en particular de la semana. Pero al desplazarse por el viewpager tendría que mostrar otro listview con los registros de ese día. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

En "CAJAS" al seleccionar una en particular se mostraría el `ViewPager` con la caja seleccionada, las 3 anteriores y las 3 posteriores... como muestro en las imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema me surge cuando quiero poner en cada fragment los diferentes `ListView` dependiendo del "ID" de cada caja. No sé cómo hacerlo. ¿Tengo que hacer 7 fragments diferentes o con 1 basta ya que cambiaría la consulta a la base de datos según el "ID" de la Caja?

Acá les dejo los códigos que he intentado hacer:

Caja.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_caja);
    cajaTvFechaCaja = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.caja_tvfechacaja);
    cajaTvIdCaja = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.caja_tvidcaja);
    listaFragments = new ArrayList<String>();
    conn = new Conexion(this,"bdatos",null,1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    idSel = extras.getString("cajasel");
    ConsultarAntPost();
    linearPuntos = findViewById(R.id.idLinearPuntos);
    agregarIndicadorPuntos(0);
    ConsultarDatos(0);
    //Abajo (al PagerAdapter) paso como parámetro el ID de la caja para pasarlo de la Activity al Fragment... No se si esto esta bien o hay algo mejor y mas eficiente
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),cantFragm,cajaTvIdCaja.getText().toString());
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewListener);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(cantAnt);
}
```

Fragment1.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        IdCaj = getArguments().getString("strIdCaja");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    vistaF1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
    cajaTotalDia1 = vistaF1.findViewById(R.id.caja_total_dia1);
    cajaDia1LvIngresos = vistaF1.findViewById(R.id.caja_dia1_lv_ingresos);
    conn = new Conexion(getContext(),"bdkios",null,1);
    consultarListaIngresos(IdCaj);
    adaptadoringr = new adaptadoringresos(getContext(),R.layout.list_view_item_ingresos,listaIngresos);
    cajaDia1LvIngresos.setAdapter(adaptadoringr);
    cajaTotalDia1.setText("$ " + totalIngr1);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"F1 - ID: " + IdCaj,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return vistaF1;
}
```

Me gustaría saber si está bien mi código y cómo solucionar el tema de mostrar en cada fragment los diferentes `ListView` con la caja en particular (segun el id). Serían 7 fragment: El seleccionado, 3 anteriores y 3 posteriores.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Si el comportamiento y uso es el mismo deja un solo fragment e inyecta en el constructor del fragment por paso de parámetros el valor del ID de Caja al seleccionar sobre el viewpager recreando el fragment en cada selección, este link puede servirte. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Comment: Y como deberia hacer para que al deslizar me tome el siguiente ID... porque me está tomando el mismo en todas las vistas del viewpager...